# Setting up teska K40 withATI radeon. End up with black screen while installation on ubuntu 14.04

Tags: drivers, nvidia, ati, xorg, cuda

For almost a week I can't set up Tesla K40 on CUDA.
Currently I have 2 GPUs 
1.Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Oland XT [Radeon HD 8670 / R5 340X / R7 250/350X]
2. Nvidia Tesla K40 active

After trying below steps I ended up with black screen:

1.Generated xorg.conf.new file by X configure 
in order to see current detected devices. When I generated I got the errors saying
a. drm report modesetting isn;t supported 
b. Number of detected devices doesn't match number of created screens.
However I still got the xorg.conf.new file therefore ignored errors.

2. Installed Cuda toolkit by these commands

$ sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404_7.0-28_amd64.deb 
$ sudo apt-get update
$ sudo apt-get install cuda

3. I made my own xorg.conf file in the /ect/X11 directory by referrring to generated xorg.conf.new file and https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/821158/setting-up-a-machine-with-a-tesla-k40-with-ubuntu-14-04-and-an-intel-on-board-graphics-card-solved-/ post (I had to change intel to radeon)
4. When I boot up there were only purple window.

5.After taking out Tesla K40 it booted up nicely. When I checked my xorg.conf file it's name was changed to xorg.conf.06252015.

6. I removed /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/xorg/extra-modules/libglx.so* file after reading a post on http://streamcomputing.eu/blog/2011-10-12/both-nvidia-gtx-and-amd-radeon-on-linux/ link(I didn't follow other steps except removing libglx.so).
7. After booting I am welcomed by black screen. Even CTRL-ALT-F1 is not working.

Because I can;t access my ubuntu 14.04 I can't show you my xorg files.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to setup with slight modification of above instructions which I got in this nvidia forum [1](https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/846241/does-tesla-k40-and-ati-radeon-work-together-/)

While installing NVIDIA drivers nvidia-libgl(or nvidia-gl) overwrites mesa-libgl. This results AMD GPU based GUI to broke. In order to prevent this I installed nvidia with --no-opengl-files option.

7. sudo ./NVIDI* --no-opengl-files

However later when installing cuda I couldn't install CUDA samples. Because It could not find libGLU.so and libGL.so.

Installing libglu1-mesa
Making symbolic link.
Reinstalling nvidia drivers

didn't solve the issue.

I just ignored installing CUDA samples since I successfully run Caffe examples on GPU which required CUDA.